# Javascript vs python: Different output for a function with two recursion branches

Tags: javascript, python, recursion

I have been translating python code to javascript with no problems but for the following example I fail to do so and don't know what is the reason. It seems that the javascript code yields a totally different output from that of python despite the similar code. I have investigated the problem and it appears that javascript doesn't execute the second recursion branch? Anyone knows how can I make the javascript code to output similarly to that of python? Thanks

1- Python code:

```
def createNode(_id, right, left):
    return {'id': _id, 'left': left, 'right': right}

n1 = createNode(1, None, None)
n2 = createNode(2, None, None)
n3 = createNode(3, None, None)
n4 = createNode(4, None, None)
n5 = createNode(1, n1, n2)
n6 = createNode(2, n3, n4)
n7 = createNode(3, n5, n6)

def DownTree(lst, node): 
    left = node['left']
    right = node['right'] 

    if(right == None):
        lst.append(node['id'])
    else:
        DownTree(lst, right)    
    if(left == None):
        lst.append(node['id'])
    else:
        print('will excute')
        DownTree(lst, left)


lst = []
DownTree(lst, n7)

print(lst)
## outputs: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

2- Javascript Code:

```
function createNode(_id, right, left){
    return {'id': _id, 'left': left, 'right': right}
}
n1 = createNode(1, undefined, undefined)
n2 = createNode(2, undefined, undefined)
n3 = createNode(3, undefined, undefined)
n4 = createNode(4, undefined, undefined)
n5 = createNode(1, n1, n2)
n6 = createNode(2, n3, n4)
n7 = createNode(3, n5, n6)

function DownTree(lst, node){ 
  left = node['left']
  right = node['right'] 

  if(right == undefined){
    lst.push(node['id'])
  }
  else{
    DownTree(lst, right)
  }  
  if(left == undefined){
    lst.push(node['id'])
  }
  else{
    console.log('not executed!')
    DownTree(lst, left)
  }
} 

lst = []
DownTree(lst, n7)
console.log(lst)
// outputs: [1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS `left` and `right` are not scoped correctly. You need to add `var` or `let` to their definitions so that they are not global

```
var left = node['left']
var right = node['right']
```